# I can't select "case" field

Tags: sql, case

I can't select one field and need help.

```
WHEN dpav.isprimary = 1
THEN ct.accountnum
ELSE concat (ct.accountnum,'_',dpav.zipcode) 
END 'Customeraccount'
```

and before **FROM** clause I want to select again case clause (Customeraccount)

```
case 
when DeliveryAddresses <> '' or ct.INVOICEACCOUNT = '' then 'Yes' 
when DeliveryAddresses <> '' or ct.INVOICEACCOUNT = '' 
 and Customeraccount LIKE '%[_]%' then 'No'
else 'No' 
end 'KeyAccount'
```

I tried with quotes ('Customeraccount') but it did not work.

Comment: In the second case, the second condition is NEVER met, since it's shadowed by the first one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use result of Case statement in another Case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691922/use-result-of-case-statement-in-another-case-statement)

Comment: Can you paste the error and the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a column alias in the same select where it is defined.

Still you can update your conditions as below and it will give you desired output.

```
case 
when (DeliveryAddresses <> '' or ct.INVOICEACCOUNT = '') and dpav.isprimary = 1 then 'Yes'
when DeliveryAddresses <> '' or ct.INVOICEACCOUNT = '' then 'No'
else 'No' 
end 'KeyAccount'
```

Even omitting second where claus will also work fine.

```
case 
when (DeliveryAddresses <> '' or ct.INVOICEACCOUNT = '') and dpav.isprimary = 1 then 'Yes'
else 'No' 
end 'KeyAccount'
```